# is there Azure service bus message expire event

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

Is there Azure service bus message expire event? .
I could see ***TimeToLive***  property according this  [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.timetolive?view=azure-dotnet). i am sending messages to azure service bus queue and need to identify when those message are expired .

Comment: You want to know how to set the ttl value when you send the message?

Comment: @GeorgeChen   if message is arrived , i could add receiver handler as this code [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/GettingStarted/BasicSendReceiveQuickStart/BasicSendReceiveQuickStart/Program.cs#L77). i am looking similar approach when message is expired

Answer (score 1):

Expired messages are dropped from the queue. There's no event.

You can enable dead-lettering of the expired messages and the dead-letter reason would indicate message expiration as the reason for the message ending up in the dead-letter queue.